# Why doesn't uint128_t have bit shift overloads for uint128_t?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

[`boost::multiprecision::uint128_t`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) doesn't seem to have an overload for the left/right shift operator when both operands are `uint128_t`s:

```
uint128_t operator<<(uint128_t, uint128_t); // Missing
uint128_t operator>>(uint128_t, uint128_t); // Also Missing
```

Some sample code:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main() {
    using uint128_t = boost::multiprecision::uint128_t;
    uint128_t number = 100;
    uint128_t ten = 10;

    auto leftShift = number << ten;  // fail
    auto rightShift = number >> ten; // fail
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://ideone.com/wP6ax3).

The error message is pretty long, so here is the (modified) first message for the left shift operator:

```
prog.cpp:8:26: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types 
                      are 'uint128_t {aka boost_template_typedef_for_uint128_t}' 
                      and 'uint128_t {aka boost_template_typedef_for_uint128_t}')
  auto leftShift = number << ten;  // fail
```

<sup>You can look at the demo for the full error messages.</sup>

Why is that the case? I don't see a reason why they wouldn't be implemented, as `unsigned a = 100u << 2u;` works perfectly fine for the same types.

Comment: They'll no doubt add it once computers can store pow(2, 128) / 8 = 4E37 bytes.  First version will however be `return 42;`

Comment: My naive guess would be "Too much work for too little benefit". When you think about it, there's no meaningful shift amount large enough to require a 128 bit (or bigger) number to represent. | Could be also to stay consistent with what the backends provide (I don't see GMP letting you do this either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because shifting so many bits to the left is rarely useful. It kind-of defines floating point representations (use `cpp_dec_float` or similar).

Here's a workaround:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a354e6c03a1df36)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::multiprecision::uint128_t v("1"), u("20");

    v = v << u.convert_to<size_t>();
    std::cout << v;
}
```

Prints

```
1048576
```